# Where is David Park's Mathematica site?

Tags: support

Anybody know the current location of David Park's Mathematica web site and, in particular, his "DrawGraphics" page that contains links to his add-on "Presentations"?

In the recent past I've tried to contact David directly using the e-mail address I have, but to no avail.

(Sorry if this is inappropriate for meta, but I haven't found another way.)

Comment: He seems to rework his old website. His new one can [be found here](https://davidandalicepark.wordpress.com/) but unfortunately without the packages. I'm not entirely sure whether this site is really *new*, but if I remeber correctly, he was writing in present tense about his wife on the old website. On the new one there is a memoriam of her. Actually, that makes me sad right now because I remember reading on the old site how they both liked to read books to each other. Something I value myself. Did you mail him on the address that's give in the About section?

Comment: @halirutan Yes, always sad to read of the loss of a partner of many years. :'-(  murray, perhaps this is what you seek: http://web.archive.org/web/20151002151435/http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/

Comment: @halirutan: Thanks for that link. The link there on the DrawGraphics/Presentation page for "FreePresentations" (the version without documentation) still works. I don't know whether the link there to purchase the full version still works. (My query was on behalf of a 3rd party who had written to me about the package.) I'm aware of David's new web site, on wordpress, that lacks a Mathematica section. In any case, I'd like to know that David is well and be able to get in touch with him.